# Caching commonly used database data in MVC 4 site

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have some commonly used data in my MVC 4 application like;

Countries
Region
City
District
Hotels

This data rarely changes, although occasion updates do occur in my MySQL database.  My questions related to this are;

1. Is it recommended to cache this data when IIS starts the site service
2. How best should this data be stored if this is a recommended technique.
3. How best should I update this data should it be changed in the database (MySQL), without restarting the website.

Note that currently the City table contains over 50,000 rows, and the hotel table has over 350,000 rows of data.

Is it possible that I can read this data from the MySQL, initially one time only, and it is loaded into memory; rather than having to read from the database every time the information is needed.

Comment: Does anybody need any additional information to answer my questions?

Comment: Why do you want to cache 50,000 rows?

Comment: Because I have a database that contains information for 50,000 cities, and over 350,000 hotels. This information does not change very often if at all. Therefore is it possible to cache it someone rather than to keep reading it from the database